# Running a Python script through Proxifier

Tags: python, python-3.x, proxy

I have a script that I use to send HTTP requests and Websocket data and I had to use an external program as I couldn't find a Websocket library that supports SOCKS5 proxies.

So, I've found about Proxifier and tried running my Python script with a rule that I have written in Proxifier but it didn't yield and good result.

Other programs seemed to work fine, chrome.exe managed to go through the proxy, and I have no idea why my Python script won't go...

Answer (score 0):

Same issues with proxifier.
Seems reason in portable version of application.
Tried standard version and everything works fine.
Hope this helps.